# Flutter) I want to change screen in ModalBottomSheet... WHAT IS PROBLEM..?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an int variable `tab1` and a function `addTab` to control the screen in `modalBottomSheet`, and I thought that when TextButton in `HandAdd1()` is pressed, a function `addTab` is executed, and changes the int variable `tab1`.

In `MyApp()`, as a result `HandAdd2()` widget is shown according to the list in `MyApp()`, but int variable `tab1` doesn't change no matter how many times I press the `TextButton` in `HandAdd1()`, so the screen doesn't change, and I don't know what the problem is.

Can you help me ?

Here's the code:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  int tab1 = 0;

  addTab (){
    setState(() {
      tab1++;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
         showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,30,20,20),
          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 50,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          ), 
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, 
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft:Radius.circular(25),
              topRight: Radius.circular(25),
             
            ),
          ),
          child: Scaffold(body:[HandAdd1(addTab:addTab) , HandAdd2()][tab1]),
        );
        
      },
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    );
);
  }
}
```

and here's HandAdd1() WIdget. (HandAdd2() is almost similar to HandAdd1())

```
class HandAdd1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const HandAdd1({Key? key, this.addTab}) : super(key: key);
  
  final void addTab;
  @override
  HandAdd1State createState() => HandAdd1State();
}

class HandAdd1State extends State<HandAdd1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
    children:[
      Align(alignment:Alignment.centerLeft, child:Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,0,),
        child:Text('''title''' ,
          ),
            ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,20,),
        child:Container(),
      ),
      
      InkWell(child: Container(
        margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,0,),
        alignment:Alignment.center,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 50,
        height:60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          
        ),
      child:Text('button' , style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white , fontWeight:FontWeight.w500 , fontSize: 20,))
      ),
        onTap: (){
          widget.addTab;
        }     
             ),
    ],
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `addTab` function to a `addTab` property as a `VoidCallback`.

In your **HandAdd1** widget,

Change from `final void addTab;` to `final VoidCallback addTab;`

And from `widget.addTab;` to `widget.addTab();`